# Webpack: Cannot statically analyse file

Tags: javascript, webpack

I have a js file with a require call which is too dynamic for Webpack to be analyzed. The file is from a dependency and there's no replacement for it (and I need that code in the bundle).

The error:

```
Cannot statically analyse 'require(..., ...)' in line 1822
```

How can I tell webpack "If file X fails, don't bother and continue"?

An improvement on that can be "If file X fails because it can't be statically analyzed, don't bother and continue".

I'm analyzing writing a plugin that can remove that piece of code and after compilation add it again (I will have requirejs loaded to resolve those requests), but it doesn't seem very easy, so I wanted to check if there's a simpler solution first.

Any pointers on how that plugin should look like would be appreciated too : )

Thanks!

Comment: "and after compilation add it again" --- what is the point to add something that would fail in runtime?

Comment: https://webpack.github.io/docs/context.html ?

Comment: Nope, the code is too complex to create a context manually, and I would still need to replace the piece of code in my dependency.

Comment: @talabes where you able to find a workaround for this?

Comment: @SimranjitSingh add that file as external is one solution

Comment: @talabes Thanks. I was able to use it as external.